# File `standalone.cls' not found

Tags: installing

I start with a fresh installation of Ubuntu 22. I installed pdflatex from the command line.

Compiling this code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

produces the error:

```
pdflatex test.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>

! LaTeX Error: File `standalone.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)
```

What is wrong and how to fix?

Comment: What did you use for installing `pdflatex`? From the error and your description it feels like you just have the binary for PDFLaTeX and don't have any other files which are required for LaTeX.

Comment: E.g., if you install LaTeX by issuing `sudo apt-get install texlive-full`, it will install binaries+package files+documentations etc.. Without knowing the command that you have used for installation it would be difficult to predict what you currently have and what you don't have.

Comment: @Niranjan `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` worked so it could be a concise answer. I can't remember the command I ran originally. The original command was suggested on the command line.

Comment: @Viesturs Ah, I am glad that it worked for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LaTeX works with binaries as well as a huge set of package and class files. So it can be thought of as a bundle. Installing a binary file like `pdflatex` without installing the other parts of the bundle is barely of any use in most of the contexts. Hence, one way to get a *useful* installation (on the operating system specified by the OP) is to use the following command on a bash terminal.

```bash
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

Comment: sudo apt install texlive-latex-extra would have been enough for this problem alone.

Comment: @gigiair I wasn't aware of this collection, so I suggested `full`, as it is pretty comprehensive.

Comment: The command `dpkg -S standalone.cls' could have done it.